# How to pass the user input data to SQL syntax in python

Tags: python, sql

I want to pass the user input variables to SQL via `pandas.read_sql_query` by using connection between pycharm IDE version 2020.2 and Microsoft SQL Server 2019 which shown by the code below :

```
InputID = int(input('Give me your input MeterpointID: ')) 
OccurDate = input('What is the beginning occurrence datetime (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss):') 
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query('select * from tblprofilewhimp_norm where 
MeterpointID = InputID and Date_M > \'OccurDate\'', conn)
```

However, this code doesn't work and the IDE showed me the error like this :

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from
> tblprofilewhimp_norm where MeterpointID = InputID and Date_M >
> 'OccurDate'': ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
> [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'InputID'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")

So, could you tell me how to handle this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: The error is indicating that the column `InputID` doesn't exist. Could you post a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look up the placeholder format used by the SQL library, then pass the values as the `params` argument to `pd.read_sql_query`.

Assuming the SQL library is pyodbc, the placeholder format is `?` and the syntax would be:

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
    'select * from tblprofilewhimp_norm where MeterpointID = ? and Date_M > ?',
    conn,
    params=(InputID, OccurDate),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use format strings to concatenate strings and variables:

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query('select * from tblprofilewhimp_norm where MeterpointID = {} and Date_M > \'{}\''.format(InputID, OccurDate), conn)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It's very clear explaination.

Comment: No, please don't do this; it's a massive security hole. Instead, use the placeholder mechanism provided by your SQL library.

Comment: This is how SQL injection happens; it's a good habit to be very paranoid any time format strings (or equivalent) are used to create an SQL statement. Sometimes it's unavoidable, but it's always high risk. It's much safer to pass the variables in the `params` argument.